# ithit-ajax-file-browser no longer works with Firefox 50

Tags: ithit-ajax-file-browser

With the latest version of Firefox 50, eanly" ithit-ajax-file-browser no longer loads folders, it just keeps "loading..."   You can see this is the case on the IT Hit Demo site as well.  https://www.webdavsystem.com/ajaxfilebrowser

Any updates or fixes coming for this?  I assume it's some sort of javascript change in Mozilla Firefox

Answer (score 0):

It seems that implementation of Document.createElementNS ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS ) was changed in Firefox 50.0.

The IT Hit Ajax File Browser (JavaScript) has to be updated to fix it.